# How to disable SSL verification in Spring Vault

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, spring-vault

I'm trying to configure Spring vault, and for some reason, I need to disable SSL verification. Is there any known way to configure Spring Vault to ignore SSL?

Comment: Hi @meldevep, did you find any answer to this?

Comment: Hey @thelearner. There is no out-of-box way to do so. One of the project contributors mentioned they do not like this idea  [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/130). You may want to rewrite some classes that will lead to accepting any certificate. 
`SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
// set up a TrustManager that trusts everything`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @meldevep. I'm facing this SSL issue from last one week. I'm able to connect to local vault server via token & AppRole authentication mechanism but I'm not able to connect to our dev vault server on AWS or Azure. Everytime, it gives SSL Peer shut down error. So, I thought if I can skip the SSL part, may be I can check if I'm able to connect to our dev vault server.

Comment: @thelearner As I said, there is no way that I'm aware of to disable ssl verification in Spring Vault. There is an alternative library from HashiCorp that provides SSL configuration out-of-box [BetterCloud/vault-java-driver](https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver#ssl-config). You may also want to check this [topic](https://www.javafixing.com/2022/04/fixed-how-to-disable-ssl-certificate.html?m=1) that may be useful for you. Cheers! That’s all I can help with. In the end I just used BetterCloud vault driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the project's github page states - there is no way to disable SSL verification in Spring Vault. Please refer to [project github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/130) . Alternatively If someone has the answer, please feel free to post